# Howto sort alphanumerical values (a1,a2,a3,...) in a CSV line after line with Python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have got an CSV file full with stuff like this:

```
L4,B4
B3,C3,B2
B2,A1,C9,F3
F1,E1
F3,E4,I9,A2,F1
K4
```

What I would like to get is:

```
B4,L4
B2,B3,C3
A1,B2,C9,F3
E1,F1
A2,E4,F1,F3,I9
K4
```

So the aim is to get it sorted in an alpanumerical manner - for all elements in a line. The number of entries per line is **not** consistent!

I already tried to get it sorted with libreoffice (using sort left to right) but I can't get it to work. Also had a look at python to get this done but without success.

Any ideas how I could get this stuff sorted - preferably by using Python?

Appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:                        
    for line in f:                                 
        print ",".join(sorted(line.rstrip().split(',')))
```

**output**

```
B4,L4
B2,B3,C3
A1,B2,C9,F3
E1,F1
A2,E4,F1,F3,I9
K4
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer - this version worked best for me. If you've got a minute it would be great if you could describe shortly how the code above works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Ashoka Lella is good, but it's not complete.

Suppose that we have the same file sample that you have provided, with a slight change:

```
L4,B4
B3,C3,B2
B2,A1,C9,F3,A10,A2
F1,E1
F3,E4,I9,A2,F1
K4
```

Just to be clear: the file is the same, except for the third line `B2,A1,C9,F3,A10,A2`, where I've added `A10` and `A2`. Now, if you run it by the accepted answer above, the result of the third line would be:

```
A1,A10,A2,B2,C9,F3
```

which is not how a human would sort the list (`A2` should be before `A10`, since 2<10). Namely, when you sort by strings - this is how it's done: sorting each next character at a time, which will result in A10 being before A2. This is why you need the [alphanum sorting algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html) and its [implementation in Python](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/). So, after you implement your alphanum key option in your sorting - the sort will be performed in a way that a human would expect. With this, instead of having a result like this one (which is not really a sorting when you look at it):

```
A1,A10,A2,B2,C9,F3
```

you will have a better answer:

```
A1,A2,A10,B2,C9,F3
```

Here's an enhanced version of Ashoka's code:

```
import re

convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print ",".join(sorted(line.rstrip().split(','), key = alphanum_key))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in file.read().split('\n'):
    l = line.split(',')
    l.sort()
```

and then write it to another file, or use it anyway you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
file_name = open('i_c.csv','rb')
for line in file_name:
    if line != '\n':
        print ",".join(sorted(line.strip().split(',')))
```